# Eclipse class navigation in package/navigator explorer

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there a plugin in eclipse where when i switch on a open class on eclipse, it will highlight that class name in package explorer or navigator. So i don't want to manually check the package declaration and explore it in package explore or navigator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first you should check which version of your eclipse, if you version is Java EE dev, then it has this function. just click the button which is 2 arrows that in the top of package explore or navigator, then you see when you change the file in editor, then the package explore or navigator explore will focus on the file that you select in editor.

Answer (score 1):

Not automatic but you can use **Alt-Shift-W** to open "Show in..." giving you options to show it in either Navigator, Package Explorer, etc.